# Google maps data layer mouse events trigger map idle event

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The Google Maps idle event is supposed to fire "when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming." ([Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/#Map), [Events example page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events))

Yet, whenever the cursor passes over an element of a data layer, the idle event fires constantly, making it useless. (See https://jsfiddle.net/162tdb53/6/)

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -28, lng: 137}
  });

  // Load GeoJSON.
  map.data.loadGeoJson(
      'https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/google.json');

  map.addListener('idle', function(event) {
    console.log('IDLE');
  });

}
```

Any insight appreciated

**UPDATE**

This bug was handled in issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74214837.
It was marked as Fixed in version 3.32 on March 7, 2018.

Comment: You can specify v=3.31 in your google maps script tag, the bug appears to be in their experimental release. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

Comment: You should also report the bug for version 3.32 in Google [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=788207). Note that experimental version 3.32 will become release in May 2018, so the 3.31 version will exist as frozen version only until August 2018: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions

Comment: Reported issuetracker.google.com/issues/74233017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the release version of the API instead of the experimental version. You can do that by just adding v=3 to the js call.

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=###&callback=initMap"></script>
```

versus

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=###&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you're not the only one. Looks like a Google Maps Api update in the last 24-hours has the map moving in the background.

Found this patch on a Drupal forum. Testing some things on my end and will let you know if we come up with anything. https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation/issues/2950361

Comment: Ah so it's a new bug- thank god, I was going out of my mind trying to track this thing. Bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74233017